# getView not called on app relaunch (Weird behaviour)

Tags: android, gridview, visibility, baseadapter

I have a gridView which I populate with aJsonObject gotten from a website, with a CustomAdapter (baseadapter).
I'm using Volley library to manage the HTTP requests (it works fine, as far as I tested).

When I launch the app, the grid is populated correctly (50 Items).
But if I exit the app -with finish()- and then click on the launcher icon, the list stays empty (the http request is successfull, but getView is never called).

**Relevant Notes:**

- I first had a similar problem for all instances (which I solved by properly setting the visibility of the gridview container -a RelativeLayout- to VISIBLE)
- The getCount() function is always returning 50 items (which is the correct value).
- After some tests, the *2nd time* I launch the app the gridview container -and the gridview itself- has visibility set to 0 (not by me)
- This is happening in all android versions.
- Important: if I Force Stop the app, then launch it, the contents load just fine (the same if I clear cache).

**Questions:**

- If getCount() is returning 50, why is getView not being called?
- Why is my element "gone" even if I forced it to visible?

Not pasting code, as I think this is a conceptual problem, and not a coding problem, by now.

Thank you in advance, Droiders.

Comment: Are you sure the adapter is properly set for the grid?

Comment: I originally was using a ListView, and changed for a GridView later, but it loads the first time (with no cache). Plus, if I kill the process, it does work (check my answer below). It's a very weird thing, and I think it might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily solved this issue by killing the android process when the user exits/finishes the app,

```
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

but I don't really like this workaround.

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem with more elegance will be appreciated.